# How can I make Guake terminal and Terminator as beautiful as gnome terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, terminator

I have the following screenshot of my Desktop:
[image]

As you can see the gnome terminal is more colorful than the others and I wonder how does Gnome terminal looks so colorful and how other terminal emulators can be as colorful as Gnome's one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look into their "Preferences" and profile sections.

Firstly, to get a colorful prompt, open `.bashrc` and find this line:

```
# force_color_prompt=yes
```

Then uncomment it by removing the `#` from the beginning of the line.

Now right click in  "terminator" and choose "Preferences", go to profiles tab, then select colors. from the pallet section you can choose different schemes:

[image]

Now your terminator looks like this:

[image]

You should be able to follow same steps for guake or any other terminal emulator.