# Terminator does not looks like the same as Gnome terminal even used system-theme color

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, terminator

Following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1020858/540746) I attempted to make on my fresh ubuntu 18.04LTS installation the teminator backgroung to look like GNOME terminal one.

But for some reason it is white (that hurts my eyes) and not dark as the following image shows:
[image: Disabled system color on terminator]

After foollowing the answer's steps and efitinh the `.bashrc` accorditly I enabled the `Use Colots From System Theme` and resulted the terminator having white color instead of the dark purple one.

So how I can bring back the dark purple color on terminator?

## Edit 1:

My system theme is called `'Ambiance'`and I found out using this command (as suggested in comments):

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you followed the instructions, you ran into the window shown below.  Please note the "Use colors from System Theme" checkbox, which should bring you back to defaults, *or* choose a color scheme you like from the built-in schemes, *or* choose custom colors for the text and background.

You *could* check the Preferences menu of Gnome-terminal to check what color schemes it is using, and set those into Terminator...

[image]

---

Update 2019-05-06

The problem here in Ubuntu 18.04 using the Ambience theme, is that Terminal and Terminator do not use the same set of "system themes".  So to make Terminator appear like Terminal, we need to define a custom background and foreground color for Terminator.

- In Terminator, access the Preferences->Profiles->Colors screen.
- Uncheck "Use colors from system theme"
- Select "Custom" from built-in schemes
- Select "white" as the text color
- Choose custom as the backgroup color, and use the color number #300A24

Terminator does not immediately change the color of the existing terminal.  Open a new tab...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I checked in terminator the `Use colors from System Theme` and gives me this result.

Comment: The default `Ambiance` theme.

Comment: Look at the question I edited it in order to provide the required information easily. As you can see the command results the value `'Ambiance'`.

Comment: I think it may come with `gnome-tweaks` package. A package that aided me with other problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93297/discussion-between-dimitrios-desyllas-and-charles-green).

Answer (score 1):

You can manually select the terminator background color via disabling (unticking) the `Use colors from system theme` and On the dropdown menu select "Custom" (translated the "Προσαρμοσμένο" from Greek language that my UI is) as seen in the following screenshot:

[image: Terminator Settings]

Then Select to change the Background Color an on the Open Window select the `+` icon:

[image: Select Color]

Then on the opened window set the color `#2C001E` as the following screenshot shows:

[image: Select color]

And then click "Select".

Alternatively you can also do it via terminal by edditing the `~/.config/terminator/config` and you will get the following output:

```
[global_config]
[keybindings]
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child1]]]
      parent = window0
      type = Terminal
    [[[window0]]]
      parent = ""
      type = Window
[plugins]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    background_color = "#2c001e"
    cursor_color = "#aaaaaa"
    foreground_color = "#f3f3f3"
```

On profiles section on your profile (usually you will use the `default` one) set on `background_color` the value `#2c001e` (or replace the whole content with the above one if you have no more profiles ;) )

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use [this](https://github.com/EliverLara/terminator-themes) repository .

There you will find various themes like these below.

[Material themes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeOCU.png)

I hope it helps. :)